# change default compiler on osx from llvm-g++ to g++

Tags: c++, macos, g++, llvm

I'd like to change my default compiler from llvm-g++ to g++ on osx, whats the cleanest/simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no “default” compiler as such. The operating system is compiler unaware. *Tools* will choose different compilers depending on different factors. Xcode for instance can be configured to use a different default compiler.

If, on the other hand, you want to configure your terminal to use a different default compiler, simply adjust the `$PATH` variable so that your GCC installation is found before your LLVM installation. In the simplest case, this can be done by adding the following line to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file (assuming you are using `bash` as the shell):

```
export PATH=path/to/gcc/:$PATH
```

(After that you need to reload your shell before the changes take effect.)

Comment: @jonathantopf If they aren’t configured to use a custom compiler, then yes. Otherwise you might have to configure their compilers explicitly. But by default, this should work.